# Windows Filtering Platform APIs on Visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio

C++ compiler crashes with the above error message.

Using VS 2019 community on Windows 10, version 1803

error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code 2.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using the wrong compiler. Head into your `C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Studio *` directory and find `VC` directory. In there is a file called `vcvarsall.bat`. Run that with the specific architecture that you have. For example, if you want x86_amd64 then run: `vcvarsall.bat x86_amd64`

What this does is setup your development environment by adding paths to your windows %path% variable.

Edit: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2019) is a link to learn more about this as well as provides a table of selecting the right compiler per a given architecture.